# Error while reading parquet using spark3.4 and java 17

Tags: apache-spark, kubernetes, amazon-s3, parquet, java-17

We are upgrading our spark job to java17+spark3.4 from java11+spark3.0
Earlier it was working fine with(java11+spark3.0) but after upgrade application is not able to read the parquet files from AWS S3. below is the error stack trace. Please help on what could be reason for this error.

```
       container name: app-executor
       container image: imagepath
       container state: terminated
       container started at: 2023-12-09T14:30:43Z
       container finished at: 2023-12-09T14:30:47Z
       exit code: 50
       termination reason: Error

Driver stacktrace:
      at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:2785)
      at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$abortStage$2(DAGScheduler.scala:2721)
      at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$abortStage$2$adapted(DAGScheduler.scala:2720)
      at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:62)
      at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray.foreach$(ResizableArray.scala:55)
      at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:49)
      at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:2720)
      at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1(DAGScheduler.scala:1206)
      at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1$adapted(DAGScheduler.scala:1206)
      at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:407)
      at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:1206)
      at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2984)
      at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2923)
      at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2912)
      at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:49)
      at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.runJob(DAGScheduler.scala:971)
      at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2263)
      at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2284)
      at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2303)
      at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2328)
      at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.$anonfun$collect$1(RDD.scala:1019)
      at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
      at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:112)
      at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:405)
      at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.collect(RDD.scala:1018)
      at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.SchemaMergeUtils$.mergeSchemasInParallel(SchemaMergeUtils.scala:73)
      at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.parquet.ParquetFileFormat$.mergeSchemasInParallel(ParquetFileFormat.scala:476)
      at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.parquet.ParquetUtils$.inferSchema(ParquetUtils.scala:132)
      at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.parquet.ParquetFileFormat.inferSchema(ParquetFileFormat.scala:78)
      at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.$anonfun$getOrInferFileFormatSchema$11(DataSource.scala:208)
      at scala.Option.orElse(Option.scala:447)
      at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.getOrInferFileFormatSchema(DataSource.scala:205)
      at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.resolveRelation(DataSource.scala:407)
      at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.loadV1Source(DataFrameReader.scala:229)
      at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.$anonfun$load$2(DataFrameReader.scala:211)
      at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:189)
      at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:211)
      at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.parquet(DataFrameReader.scala:563)
      at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.parquet(DataFrameReader.scala:562)
      at app.spark.reader.ParquetReader.read(ParquetReader.java:58)
      at app.spark.reader.SparkJob.run(SparkJob.java:49)
      at app.spark.reader.SparkJobRunner.run(SparkJobRunner.java:43)
      at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunner(SpringApplication.java:768)
      at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunners(SpringApplication.java:752)
      at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:314)
      at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1303)
      at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1292)
      at net.jpmchase.gbpde.pir.eod.Application.main(Application.java:20)
      at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
      at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
      at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
      at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
      at org.apache.spark.deploy.JavaMainApplication.start(SparkApplication.scala:52)
      at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:1020)
      at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:192)
      at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:215)
      at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.doSubmit(SparkSubmit.scala:91)
      at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$$anon$2.doSubmit(SparkSubmit.scala:1111)
      at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:1120)
      at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
```

Answer (score 0):

According to [this](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/util/SparkExitCode.scala), exit code 50 indicates that an uncaught exception was thrown.

Can you include the logs of the executor container?